# Getting weird struct and typedef errors in Win consoleapi using MinGW-w64

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

Below is the compile log. All of these errors are either from Wincon.h or Wincontypes.h . Everything else, including my code, works. I'm using **MinGW-w64 (v8.1.0)**, it doesn't give any errors for Winapi or ConsoleApi3. I am helpless at this point. Visual Studio (MSBuild) compiles it without a problem.

```
g++ MainConsole.cpp -o run -mconsole
```

```
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:21,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/wincontypes.h:36:16: error: redefinition of 'struct _COORD'
 typedef struct _COORD {
                ^~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:17:18: note: previous definition of 'struct _COORD'
   typedef struct _COORD {
                  ^~~~~~


In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:22:18: note: previous definition of 'struct _SMALL_RECT'
   typedef struct _SMALL_RECT {
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:21,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/wincontypes.h:46:3: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int SMALL_RECT'
 } SMALL_RECT, *PSMALL_RECT;
   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:

In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:27:17: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _SMALL_RECT* PSMALL_RECT'
   } SMALL_RECT,*PSMALL_RECT;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:78:18: note: previous definition of 'struct _WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD'
   typedef struct _WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD {
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:21,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/wincontypes.h:112:3: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD'
 } WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD, *PWINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:80:5: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD'
   } WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD,*PWINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:21,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/wincontypes.h:112:31: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int* PWINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD'
 } WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD, *PWINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD;
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:80:32: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD* PWINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD'
   } WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD,*PWINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD;
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:21,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/wincontypes.h:114:16: error: redefinition of 'struct _MENU_EVENT_RECORD'
 typedef struct _MENU_EVENT_RECORD {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:82:18: note: previous definition of 'struct _MENU_EVENT_RECORD'
   typedef struct _MENU_EVENT_RECORD {
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:21,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/wincontypes.h:116:3: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int MENU_EVENT_RECORD'
 } MENU_EVENT_RECORD, *PMENU_EVENT_RECORD;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:84:5: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _MENU_EVENT_RECORD MENU_EVENT_RECORD'
   } MENU_EVENT_RECORD,*PMENU_EVENT_RECORD;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:21,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/wincontypes.h:116:23: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int* PMENU_EVENT_RECORD'
 } MENU_EVENT_RECORD, *PMENU_EVENT_RECORD;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:84:24: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _MENU_EVENT_RECORD* PMENU_EVENT_RECORD'
   } MENU_EVENT_RECORD,*PMENU_EVENT_RECORD;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:21,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/wincontypes.h:118:16: error: redefinition of 'struct _FOCUS_EVENT_RECORD'
 typedef struct _FOCUS_EVENT_RECORD {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:86:18: note: previous definition of 'struct _FOCUS_EVENT_RECORD'
   typedef struct _FOCUS_EVENT_RECORD {
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:21,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/wincontypes.h:120:3: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int FOCUS_EVENT_RECORD'
 } FOCUS_EVENT_RECORD, *PFOCUS_EVENT_RECORD;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:88:5: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _FOCUS_EVENT_RECORD FOCUS_EVENT_RECORD'
   } FOCUS_EVENT_RECORD,*PFOCUS_EVENT_RECORD;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:21,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/wincontypes.h:120:24: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int* PFOCUS_EVENT_RECORD'
 } FOCUS_EVENT_RECORD, *PFOCUS_EVENT_RECORD;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:88:25: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _FOCUS_EVENT_RECORD* PFOCUS_EVENT_RECORD'
   } FOCUS_EVENT_RECORD,*PFOCUS_EVENT_RECORD;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:21,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/wincontypes.h:122:16: error: redefinition of 'struct _INPUT_RECORD'
 typedef struct _INPUT_RECORD {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:90:18: note: previous definition of 'struct _INPUT_RECORD'
   typedef struct _INPUT_RECORD {
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:21,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/wincontypes.h:131:3: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int INPUT_RECORD'
 } INPUT_RECORD, *PINPUT_RECORD;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:99:5: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _INPUT_RECORD INPUT_RECORD'
   } INPUT_RECORD,*PINPUT_RECORD;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:21,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/wincontypes.h:131:18: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int* PINPUT_RECORD'
 } INPUT_RECORD, *PINPUT_RECORD;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:99:19: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _INPUT_RECORD* PINPUT_RECORD'
   } INPUT_RECORD,*PINPUT_RECORD;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:21,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/wincontypes.h:143:16: error: redefinition of 'struct _CHAR_INFO'
 typedef struct _CHAR_INFO {
                ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:107:18: note: previous definition of 'struct _CHAR_INFO'
   typedef struct _CHAR_INFO {
                  ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:21,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/wincontypes.h:149:3: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int CHAR_INFO'
 } CHAR_INFO, *PCHAR_INFO;
   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:113:5: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _CHAR_INFO CHAR_INFO'
   } CHAR_INFO,*PCHAR_INFO;
     ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:21,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/wincontypes.h:149:15: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int* PCHAR_INFO'
 } CHAR_INFO, *PCHAR_INFO;
               ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:113:16: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _CHAR_INFO* PCHAR_INFO'
   } CHAR_INFO,*PCHAR_INFO;
                ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:21,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/wincontypes.h:151:16: error: redefinition of 'struct _CONSOLE_FONT_INFO'
 typedef struct _CONSOLE_FONT_INFO {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:146:18: note: previous definition of 'struct _CONSOLE_FONT_INFO'
   typedef struct _CONSOLE_FONT_INFO {
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:21,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/wincontypes.h:154:3: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int CONSOLE_FONT_INFO'
 } CONSOLE_FONT_INFO, *PCONSOLE_FONT_INFO;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:149:5: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _CONSOLE_FONT_INFO CONSOLE_FONT_INFO'
   } CONSOLE_FONT_INFO,*PCONSOLE_FONT_INFO;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:21,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/wincontypes.h:154:23: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int* PCONSOLE_FONT_INFO'
 } CONSOLE_FONT_INFO, *PCONSOLE_FONT_INFO;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:149:24: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _CONSOLE_FONT_INFO* PCONSOLE_FONT_INFO'
   } CONSOLE_FONT_INFO,*PCONSOLE_FONT_INFO;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:66:16: error: redefinition of 'struct _CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX'
 typedef struct _CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:297:16: note: previous definition of 'struct _CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX'
 typedef struct _CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:73:3: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX'
 } CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX, *PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:304:3: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX'
 } CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX, *PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:73:25: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int* PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX'
 } CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX, *PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:304:25: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX* PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX'
 } CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX, *PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:107:16: error: redefinition of 'struct _CONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO'
 typedef struct _CONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:151:18: note: previous definition of 'struct _CONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO'
   typedef struct _CONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO {
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:111:3: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int CONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO'
 } CONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO, *PCONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:155:5: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _CONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO CONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO'
   } CONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO,*PCONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:111:28: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int* PCONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO'
 } CONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO, *PCONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO;
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:155:29: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _CONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO* PCONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO'
   } CONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO,*PCONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO;
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:127:16: error: redefinition of 'struct _CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO'
 typedef struct _CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:306:16: note: previous definition of 'struct _CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO'
 typedef struct _CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:132:3: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO'
 } CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO, *PCONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:311:3: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO'
 } CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO, *PCONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:7,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ConsoleApi3.h:132:26: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int* PCONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO'
 } CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO, *PCONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/Windows.h:74,
                 from F:\PROJECTS\gpge\GPGE\Dependencies.h:5,
                 from MainConsole.cpp:6:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wincon.h:311:26: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct _CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO* PCONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO'
 } CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO, *PCONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO;
```

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve] and [edit] your question to show it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude well you see that's the problem. That all of the errors are inside the Windows apis, so they are outside of my control. I could create a simple app that uses AllocConsole(), but that would result in the exact same amount of errors. The problem is not with my code (I checked it with MSBuild), but that the compiler just doesnt understand some references that are in Wincontypes.h

Comment: The *root cause* of the error is unlikely to be in the system headers. It's much more likely  there's a mistake in your code.

Comment: AFAIK, you shouldn't need to include "ConsoleApi3.h" explicitly if you include "Windows.h". It's possible that there's something a bit off with the mingw headers, but it's more likely to be caused by something that your code does before including those headers.

Comment: @molbdnilo THIS IS THE SOLUTION! Thank you very much! I commented out the ConsoleApi3 include and now it compiles perfectly!!!!

Answer (score 0):

"AFAIK, you shouldn't need to include "ConsoleApi3.h" explicitly if you include "Windows.h". It's possible that there's something a bit off with the mingw headers, but it's more likely to be caused by something that your code does before including those headers."
-- @molbdnilo has the solution. This is new to me, looks like MSBuild checked overlaps before compiling, MinGW doesn't.